# Alphabetical array sort - lowercase first

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Given the array :

```
var myArray = ['d','a','k','v','z','A','t','G']
```

If I were to use :

```
myArray.sort()
```

The result would be :

```
myArray = ['A','G','a','d','k','t','v','z']
```

Is there a way of modifying the sort function or the output to put the uppercase letters at the end of the array like this :

```
myArray = ['a','d','k','t','v','z','A','G']
```

Either pure Javascript or jQuery would be OK.

Comment: [Yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @Pat: Do you know that you are the final part of an answer to a baseball trivia question which starts out, "Dave McNally, Mike Cuellar, Jim Palmer, and ..."?

Comment: I didn't. But considering I'd only heard of the (more famous) Pat Dobson after a google search of my name I'm not suprised..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test the first character and apply compare:

```js
var myArray = ['d', 'a', 'k', 'v', 'z', 'A', 't', 'G', 'V'];

myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a[0] === a[0].toLocaleLowerCase() && b[0] === b[0].toLocaleLowerCase() ||
        a[0] === a[0].toLocaleUpperCase() && b[0] === b[0].toLocaleUpperCase()) {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    }
    if (a[0] === a[0].toLocaleLowerCase()) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(myArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of the array sort using the compare function:

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b){

    var test = a.charCodeAt(0) <= 90 && b.charCodeAt(0) <= 90;

    if(test) return a.charCodeAt(0)-b.charCodeAt(0);
    else if(a.charCodeAt(0) <= 90) return 1;
    else if(b.charCodeAt(0) <= 90) return -1;
    else return a.charCodeAt(0)-b.charCodeAt(0);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

once you have got this array

```
myArray = ['a','d','k','t','v','z','A','G']
```

do this to get it sorted by `myArray = ['A','G','a','d','k','t','v','z']`

```
var tempArray = myArray.join("").split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
myArray = tempArray.slice(1).concat( tempArray [0].split("") );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom [compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) `myArray.sort(compareFunction)`. Inside of the function you can use 
conditions like `if(a === a.toUpperCase())` and so on to create logic that you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = ['d','a','k','v','z','A','t','G'];
_.each(myArray, function(item){
    if(item.charCodeAt(0) > 96){
        smallArr.push(item)
    }
    else{
        captArray.push(item)
    }
});
smallArr.sort();
captArray.sort();
myArray = [];
myArray.push.apply(myArray, smallArr.concat(captArray));
```